# Custom directive for ng-model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using input type="date" in angular js as follow.

```
<input type="date" ng-model="form.dateValue">
```

1) When submit, convert form.dateValue to specified date format
2) When retrieve from api call, convert form.dateValue to Date Object

My solution:

```
$scope.submitForm = function() {
    form.dateValue = // logic to convert to specific date format
}

$scope.retrieveForm = function() {
    form.dateValue = // logic to convert to Date object
}
```

My actual problem:
It is tedious and repetitive to repeat each of this process whenever there is a form that contain input type="date".

My expected solution:

```
<input type="date" date-model="form.dateValue">

angular.directive('dateModel', function() {

});
```

Note: Just ignore the logic need for the date conversion as i have implemented date

Comment: where is retrieveForm() called?

Comment: Write a custom filter to do the conversion and then you can just use that wherever you need.

Comment: @Jois submitForm is called during create/edit mode of the form and retrieveForm is called during view mode of the form. The logic to determine it would be `if(formMode.view) || if (formMode.edit)`

Comment: @Jois  However, i would expect that the directive would be able to tell if the custom ng-model is getting the input from user or retrieving value from a source in this case without refering to formMode.view and formMode.edit.